# Link to open tab from menu help. jQuery Tabslet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to link to a certain tab (Portfolio Tab) on a page from the main menu of a website, so when clicked it goes to that page with that portfolio tab open.

So far I've come up with this (using jQuery Tabslet) which works when not on the same page, but doesn't work if the user happens to be on the same page as the tabs, and so does nothing.

The link I use in the main menu is /about/#tab-3 which is doing the job of going to the about page with the portfolio tab open.

I thought I may need to trigger a page refresh when on the same page? And perhaps remove the #tab-3 from the url too.

Not being a jQuery expert, I unfortunately just don't know.

Here is the code so far

Thanks in advance.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 $('.tabs').tabslet({
  active :1,
  animation : true,
  container: '.tabs-container'
 });



 var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );
 var anchor = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');

  if (anchor.length > 0){
  anchor.click();
  } 

 window.onload = function () {

  if (location.hash) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

 };


});
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific bout what's not working? Also provide a link to the docs for that particualr plugin. There are lots and lots of tabs plugins around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advise: Always mention a reference to the plugin you use. I assume here you talk about [this one](http://vdw.github.io/Tabslet/).

This plugin acts on tab click only.

So when using a window `hash` in a link from another page like you do, you have to "simulate" a click on the tab.

So you will use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to find the anchor having a `href` corresponding to the hash...
And click it.

```
window.onload = function () {

  if (location.hash) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $("a[href='"+location.hash+"']").click();  // Add this!
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks Louys, yours is a bit tidier than mine.

The other thing was getting the portfolio tab to open with a menu link if on the same page as the tabs (rather than elsewhere on the site)

So I used this, which seems to have done the trick.

`$(".portfolio").click(function() {
     $('.tabs').trigger('show', '#portfolio');
});`